# Why are icons on my mobile-page displayed incorrectly in mobile-chrome?

Tags: css, mobile

I got my jquery-mobile(1.3.2)-page http://www.bestellbaer.de/app/guest/mobile/order/orderPoint.xhtml?orderPointId=6

On this page, I am using [jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme) for design and [jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack) for having additional icons.

When viewing  the page in android(4.3)-default browser (on Google Nexus), everything is displayed correctly. But viewing the page in mobile-chrome (28.0.1500.94) or mobile-firefox(22.0), some icons are moved for some pixels.

What is the reason for this, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack is not compatible with jquery-1.3. By correcting css, the icons are displayed correctly. See https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack/issues/55 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to applying more large pixel size image in your page it will give you better  performance in mobile browser as related to your device.
refer this link http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/18/seven-guidelines-for-designing-high-performance-mobile-user-experiences/

Comment: Thanks for your response! The article at smashingmagazine.com is interesting in general, but I cannot see a concret relationship to my question.